# VIewPager with two items - Android

Tags: android, slider, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager and it is working. It is showing one image and text on every page.

This is my adapter:

```
private class SuggestionsAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewPager pager;

    public SuggestionsAdapter(ViewPager pager) {
        this.pager = pager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(gallery.size(), true);
        } else if (position == gallery.size() + 1) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return gallery.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_suggestion_layout, container, false);

        ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        ivImage.setImageBitmap(gallery.get(position));

        // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

And I'm using very simple in my code:

```
ViewPager vpSuggestions = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpSuggestions);
SuggestionsAdapter sugAdapter = new SuggestionsAdapter(vpSuggestions);
vpSuggestions.setAdapter(sugAdapter);
```

This is mu xml for slider:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/suggestions"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/vpSuggestions" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is xml for one page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivImage1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cat_321_sofa" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Because the size of pager is rectangle (small height, huge width) I want to show two images in one page.

The pager now looks like this image:
[image]

I want to be like this image:
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Please share your xml also.

Comment: "I want to show two images in one page. How can I do that?" By creating a layout that contains 2 ImageViews ?

Comment: @2Dee I'm not sure about that, I got only one array, how can I get position for 2 images to fill them from array ?

Comment: did your mean is `getPageWidth`? override that method and return `(1 / nPages);`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan hmm that will be nice solution, let me check....

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Hmm it is not working. Pages don't show any page...

Comment: what is your mean about don't show any page? can you post your code

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I only add, as you said:
        Override
        public float getPageWidth(int position) {
            return (1 / gallery.size());
        }

Comment: try `return (1 / 2);` to see two page in one view, as you return `1/gallery.zise()` view is very very small and you can't see anything

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I tried like that, but again no images. So I find solution: return (super.getPageWidth(position) / 2);
Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to override getPageWidth() and divide it with 2

```
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return (super.getPageWidth(position) / 2);
    }
```